# VirtualBox keeps on giving me errors!

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, virtualbox, chroot, chrome-os

So I installed VirtualBox and used [this guide](https://techblog.jeppson.org/2015/11/install-virtualbox-on-a-chromebook/)

After I followed this at the end I got some errors

```
     (xenial)cloud@localhost:~$ virtualbox
    WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
     available for the current kernel (3.8.11) or it failed to
     load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by

       sudo /sbin/rcvboxdrv setup

     You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
```

After this I do what it says

```
    (xenial)cloud@localhost:~$ sudo /sbin/rcvboxdrv setup
    [sudo] password for cloud: 
    Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules ...done.
    Removing old VirtualBox pci kernel module ...done.
    Removing old VirtualBox netadp kernel module ...done.
    Removing old VirtualBox netflt kernel module ...done.
    Removing old VirtualBox kernel module ...done.
    Recompiling VirtualBox kernel modules ...done.
    Starting VirtualBox kernel modules ...failed!
    (modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why)
```

Now I am stressed and did some research couldn't find anything and did `dmesg` and got:

```
    [  623.046997] Chromium OS LSM: init_module locking-ignored
    module="/lib/modules/3.8.11/misc/vboxdrv.ko" pid=26349cmdline="/sbin/modprobe vboxdrv"
    [  623.055330] vboxdrv: Found 2 processor cores
    [  623.056117] supdrvGipCreate: failed to allocate the GIP page. rc=-26
```

And now I am stuck!

Comment: The word on the street is that you need to upgrade your kernel headers: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/7535

Comment: i get a different error code tho